# Manually setting limits and ticks on x-axis after coord_flip() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reproduce a plot from Healy's *Data visualization* (p.116, copied under) using my own data. While I manage to reproduce the figure, I want to manually edit the limits and ticks on the x-axis. The coding gets confusing as I need to use `coord_flip()` for the plot.

The x-axis should go from 0 to 6, with ticks per 1 unit. I have tried a dozen options now, and none give me what I want. Hopefully someone has input on how to solve this.

Here's my code:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = reorder(group,-yvar), y = yvar))

p <- p + geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(ymin = lbci,
                                         ymax = ubci)) +
  labs(x= "", y= "yvar_label") + coord_flip() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 5, linetype="dotted", color = "red", size=1.5) +
  theme_bw() 
p
```

[image: Figure 5.15 in Healy's Data Visualization]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to define a continuous variable's axis, so you should use the `scale_y_continuous()` function for your plot, and define the breaks you want.

Here's a dummy example :

```r
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)
p <- ggplot(data = iris[c(1:3, 52:55, 102:105),], mapping = aes(x = reorder(Species,-Petal.Width), y = Petal.Width))

p + geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(ymin = 0, ymax = 3)) +
  labs(x= "", y= "yvar_label") + coord_flip() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 5, linetype="dotted", color = "red", size=1.5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 3, by = 0.5), limits = c(0,3)) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Edit: For plot limits, you should give the `limits` arguments to the `scale_x/y_continuous()` function.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried: scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 6, by = 1)). While this sets the correct limit on the x-axis, the ticks are default 2 units (i.e. 0, 2, etc.). Adding ylim(0,6) returns error: "Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.", while xlim() also returns an error.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the fact you have to include the limits in the `scale_y_continuous()` function directly if you use it. I'll update my answer